# Example of a vector space with different addition/scalar multiplication operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have learned that a **vector space** is a set of elements called **vectors**, on which are defined an **addition** operation and a **scalar multiplication** operation with the scalars in some field $F$. However, all the examples of vector fields I know ($\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$, $\mathbb{F}^{(n, n)}$, etc) all use the "normal" operations of addition and scalar multiplication.

As an example, let's consider the set $S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \lvert x + y = 10\}$, for instance. With the intuitive definitions of addition and scalar multiplication ($(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$ and $k(a, b) = (ka, kb)$), I can verify that this is a vector space, but I can't think of any *other* definitions of the addition/scalar multiplication operation that still makes this set a vector space.

Could someone provide and explain a nonobvious example of addition/scalar multiplication operations that still keeps the set as a vector space?

Comment: There is a bijection betweem that set and the set $\Bbb{C}^{2023}$. Fix such a bijection $\Phi$. Then, there is a unique structure of a 2023-dimensional complex vector space on the set $S$ such that $\Phi$ becomes an isomorphism (of 2023-dimensional complex vector spaces).

Comment: Are you sure your example is a vector space? ;)

Comment: In practice this sort of thing doesn't really matter. Almost every example of a vector space you'll come across is built out of "normal" addition and scalar multiplication (typically of functions).

Comment: The key-word underlying peek-a-boo's comment is [Transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving Crazy Vector Space with addition and multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124750/proving-crazy-vector-space-with-addition-and-multiplication)

Comment: How did you "verify that this is a vector space"? To have a vector space, the eight basic vector axioms must be satisfied.

Comment: Your set is not a vector space, because it is not closed under the operations: for example, $(10,0)$ lies in your set, but $2(10,0) = (20,0)$ does not. Likewise, even though $(10,0)$ and $(0,10)$ are both elements of $S$, their sum as you have defined them, $(10,0)+(0,10) = (10,10)$ does not lie in $S$. You do not have a vector space.

Comment: By the way, you *can* make your set $S$ into a vector space (in many different ways), with other "additions" and "scalar multiplications": if $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers with $a+b=10$,  you can define addition in $S$ by $(x,y)\oplus(z,w) = (x+z-a,y+w-b)$, and scalar multiplication by $\alpha\odot(x,y) = (\alpha x + (1-\alpha)a,\alpha y + (1-\alpha)b)$, and you will get a vector space.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an obvious example, but you can prove it by straightforward computations.

Consider $V=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x>0\}$ with the following operations

$$ (x,y,z)\oplus (a,b,c)=(x\cdot a,y+b+3,z+c)$$
$$ \alpha \otimes (x,y,z)=(x^\alpha,\alpha \cdot y +3(\alpha -1),\alpha \cdot z)$$

Of course, $+$ and $\cdot$ are the usual sum and multiplication. It can seem weird, but the null element is $(1,-3,0)$.

Comment: This vector space is the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of three vector spaces, $V = V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_3,$ where $V_1$ is the space I present in my answer, $V_2$ is like a translated $\mathbb R,$ and $V_3$ is just $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @md2perpe yes it is.

Answer (score 5):

An example that I remember from my first year at university:

Take $V=(0,\infty)$ with $v_1\oplus v_2 = v_1 v_2$ and $k\otimes v = v^k$ for $v,v_1,v_2\in V$ and $k\in\mathbb R.$

This is though isomorphic with $\mathbb R$ by the isomorphism $\phi(v) = \ln v.$